# JQuery Datepicker UI dateformat

Tags: jquery, datepicker

So I have this code and it is working good.

```
$('#txt').datepicker({
onClose: function (selectedDate) {
    var oneday = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; //ms*sec*min*hrs
    var today = new Date();
    var selected = new Date(selectedDate);
    var diff = parseInt((selected - today) / oneday);
    if (diff <= -1) {
        alert('Not valid. Pick a day in the future.');
        $('#txt').val('');
    } else if (diff <= 3 && diff >= 0) {
        alert('Hum...You know we need at least two days to be prepared, right?');
     //   $('#txt').val('');
    }
}
});
```

Now I need to use the following date format: `dd/mm/yy`.

If I use

`$('#txt').datepicker({
dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", 
onClose:(...)`

I get the date format I want, but the onClose function do not work right anymore, cause `var today` and `var selected` would not follow the new format (the math would be ruined).

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value of `selectedDate` is `'2-8-2014'` using `dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'` (representing August 2nd) then you can covert to to a javascript `Date` object as follows

```
var d = selectedDate.split('-');
var selected = new Date(d[2], d[1] - 1, d[0]);
```

You can now compare it with the `var today = new Date();`

Comment: Thanks, but would you adapt my code to this? You can test it [here] (http://jsfiddle.net/luroch/UF82K/18/)

Comment: Refer [updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/UF82K/19/) using `dd-mm-yy` format. PS. My code above should have been `var selected = new Date(d[2], d[1] - 1, d[0]);`

Comment: You did it, man! Thanks a lot. Save my day. For everybody know, here is the working code (I've only changed the format from `dd-mm-yy` to `dd/mm/yy`: http://jsfiddle.net/luroch/UF82K/22/

Answer (score 0):

use the below (zh_CN) settings for the date picker setting, and change whatever you want, including the date format.

```
/* Chinese initialisation for the jQuery UI date picker plugin. */
/* Written by Cloudream (cloudream@gmail.com). */
jQuery(function($){
        $.datepicker.regional['zh-CN'] = {
                closeText: '关闭',
                prevText: '&#x3c;上月',
                nextText: '下月&#x3e;',
                currentText: '今天',
                monthNames: ['一月','二月','三月','四月','五月','六月',
                '七月','八月','九月','十月','十一月','十二月'],
                monthNamesShort: ['一','二','三','四','五','六',
                '七','八','九','十','十一','十二'],
                dayNames: ['星期日','星期一','星期二','星期三','星期四','星期五','星期六'],
                dayNamesShort: ['周日','周一','周二','周三','周四','周五','周六'],
                dayNamesMin: ['日','一','二','三','四','五','六'],
                weekHeader: '周',
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                firstDay: 1,
                isRTL: false,
                showMonthAfterYear: true,
                yearSuffix: '年'};
        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['zh-CN']);
});
```

So, to be more simple, in your case, you can simply use the below code before you call the datepicker function:

```
jQuery(function($){
        $.datepicker.setDefaults({
                dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
        });
});
```

Comment: This second code only changes the format, but the onClose function does not work with it (math is wrong).

Comment: The first code I could not understand (newbie here)...would you adapt my code to this? You can test it [here] (jsfiddle.net/luroch/UF82K/18)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UF82K/25/ Oh sorry, I think I misunderstood your question, and thought that you only want to change the format. This solution just give you a simple way to change the format.

Answer (score -1):

Use Javascript's [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object.

You have to split the selected date into multiple pieces like so:

```
var splitDate = selected.split("/");
var day = splitDate[0];
var month = splitDate[1];
var year = splitDate[2];

var selected = new Date(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
```

Comment: `var foo = new Date("07-08-14") returns `Jul 08 2014` but OP wants `Aug 07 2014`

Comment: Thanks, but would you adapt my code to this? You can test it [here] (http://jsfiddle.net/luroch/UF82K/18/)

Comment: @MauroLopes np glad I could help.